# Angular, data loss when page refresh

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

I have a little question in Angular.

I have a button in a component that when pressed, selects a game and runs a function and that function just sends the game to a service called **SelectedGameService**, so that I can understand which game was selected. Here are my codes;

The button in **games.component.html**;

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="handleDetails(game)" style="position: absolute; top:86%; background-color: #0909CD;" routerLink="/games/game-details/{{game.title}}">See The Game Details</a>
```

As I have said, the handleDetails(game) function sends the game to that function. That handleDetails function in game.component.ts is;

```
handlePrice(game) {
    this.selectedGameService.selectedGame = game;
  }
```

That function send the game to selectedGameService. here are my codes in that service;

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Games } from '../games/Games';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'; 

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SelectedGameService {

  selectedGame: Games;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.selectedGame = new Games;
  }
```

So basically this service creates a new game and equals it to the game that triggered the **handlePrice(game)** function.

Here is my problem. When I run the code, it runs perfectly in browser. When I press "See The Game Details" button I can see the page as I want, but when I refresh the browser while at that page, all the information of the game disappears. How can I solve  this problem?

You can see the before and after pictures of when I refresh the browser while at that page.

Thank you from now.

[Before Refreshing The Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02T9f.png)

[After Refreshing The Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEtHN.png)

Comment: if you want to persist your data between refresh you need to use a mechanism like localstotage or sessionstorage, then in your service check before going to the backend if you have data stored in localstorage. There is no way you press F5 and your data will be there without using something to persist. A Refresh reload all the scripts for the page

Comment: Are you getting game details from some api or just locally you have it stored??

Comment: You should let game-details handle the service call, not as you have it now using a click on that link. You have the game title in the URL anyway..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data stored in variables in services will be cleared if the browser is refreshed . One way to solve this is by using session or local storage to store the data:

```
    handleDetails(value) {
      localStorage.setItem('key', value);
      }
```

To retrieve data from local storage:

```
localStorage.getItem('key');
```

Answer (score 4):

The data which you store in a service resides in the memory. When you refresh the page, the browser frees up the memory and give your app a clean slate to write on.

If you want to maintain **state** across page refreshes you should go for **localStorage** for saving your data.

The process you should follow is:

1. Whenever you call your service to save the state, your service should internally save it to **localStorage**.
2. When you refresh the page, you should first check whether some state is already present in the **localStorage** or not. If it is, then you should get that data and populate the table otherwise start from the beginning.

[You can read up about localStorage from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: How can that be true.  Services are singletons in the app, and therefore their state is separate from the context of a page, right?

Comment: Yes, services are singletons but at the end they are JavaScript functions/classes which get executed when a page loads and get removed when the tab/browser is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use **Local storage** / **Session storage**.

Whatsoever data is stored in service gets lost on page reload and if you use local storage / session storage it becomes easier to store that data and
make your logic in such manner that before page reload completely you use these storage to get that data and component works accordingly.